# Web Service reference changed

Tags: web-services

I have publish one webservice on server let say on abc.com server. now more than 10 client subscribe for this webservice.

Now I want to shift same web service to server xyz.com and want to close server abc.com.

So without updating client how can i make this move successful so my client Web Service do not need to update anything from their side.

Answer (score 1):

You likely can't.  Most users will have client side configuration that will need to be changed to point to the new url.

*If* you control the dns entries, you could decommission server `abc.com` and point it's old dns entry to the same server as `xyz.com`.